# Best way to collapse invisible Java Swing components

Tags: java, swing, layout, visibility, miglayout

I have some Java Swing components whose `visible` property is set to false. When they are not visible I do not want them to take up any space in the layout. What is the best way to accomplish this?

I am looking to emulate the behavior of WPF's [`Visibility.Collapsed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visibility).

**EDIT**: I am using MiGLayout. As kiheru describes in the answer, the problem I was having is particular to MiGLayout, not Swing layouts in general.

Comment: Isn't that the default behaviour when the layout is done properly using layout managers?

Comment: I have a JLabel whose `text` property is set to a string. When I set its `visible` property to false the label still takes up space, but the text is not displayed. I am using MiGLayout set to `flowy`.

Comment: That's apparently of an oddity of MigLayout. You need to set `hidemode` to something else than the default. See http://www.miglayout.com/whitepaper.html

Comment: @kiheru, that should be an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MigLayout` treats invisible components by default the same way as visible components. You need to specify `hidemode` for other kind of behaviour. From the [documentation](http://www.miglayout.com/whitepaper.html), the possible values are:

1. Default. Means that invisible components will be handled exactly as if they were visible.
2. The size of the component (if invisible) will be set to 0, 0.
3. The size of the component (if invisible) will be set to 0, 0 and the gaps will also be set to 0 around it.
4. Invisible components will not participate in the layout at all and it will for instance not take up a grid cell.